# How to cancel async action with rxjs?

Tags: rxjs, cancellation

I want to trigger an async action via button `Async increment` but cancel it by clicking button `cancel`.

My code with `race` of `rxjs` does not work.

Is there any way to implement it?

https://codesandbox.io/s/zk5oy3zj7x

Answer (score 1):

welcome.

`switchMap` cancel the previous request (completing the previous inner observable) if a new request comes before the previous is completed.
If you want to cancel request with a new stream, you could merge your stream with the "action one", and let switchMap to decide what to do.

```
merge(
  increment$.pipe(mapTo(true)),
  cancelIncrement$.pipe(mapTo(false))
).pipe(
  switchMap((run) => new Promise(resolve => {
    if(run) 
      setTimeout(() => resolve(2), 2000);
  }))
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50876627/why-observable-race-not-working-if-one-of-observable-stop-emit-events